# BFS on a graph and BFS on a tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, artificial-intelligence, game-theory

I found the following question in my book and I have no clue on what the answer should be:

> What is the condition on search graph so that BFS Algorithm for graph and BFS Algorithm for tree **generate and expand** identical nodes in the same order?

Please Note you don't have to write a proof as I will prove it myself and post under my question accordingly to help others in the future (completing your answer)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to credit the source where you encountered this question.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: We're not particularly looking for posts that consist solely of the text of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I doubt that the question is answerable without seeing how exactly your book defines "BFS Algorithm for graph" and "BFS Algorithm for tree".

Comment: Just over the top of my head, if the graph is a tree, then BFS traversal would be same.

Answer (score 0):

If given graph is a tree (in other words, if tnhe graph doesn't contain cycles/loop/self-edges/self-loops), then the BFS traversal (level order traversal) would be the same.